# Changing WMF color

Tags: delphi, colors, wmf

i have been trying to change colors on a wmf canvas in Delphi, with usual images i just run a scanline or by running a loop on each X and Y pixel and give it a new color code, but with MetaCanvas this method doesnt work, maybe because it is not actually an image but instead a list of GDI functions. I read somewhere that i would need to decompile and recompile the metafile for changing color properties in it. But i dont have a clue how i will do it or if there is another easy way for it.

If anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mechanism for you to modify the contents of a meta file.

Call [`EnumEnhMetaFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162613.aspx) passing a callback function, [`EnhMetaFileProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162606.aspx). The callback function is called for each record in the metafile. You can take a copy of this record, modify it, and then pass it to [`PlayEnhMetaFileRecord`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162801.aspx).

So, you could look for records that specified colours, and make whatever modifications you need.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. sorry for being late on selecting the answer